# How to move a git note to a different commit?

Tags: git

I've made a note on the wrong commit by mistake. Is there a easy way to move it in whole to a different commit?

I'm hoping for a way to semantically re-parent a note onto a different commit, But whatever is easiest would be great to know. I suspect the easiest option will be to copy paste the text with a desktop clipboard.

Comment: By note do you mean a commit message?

Comment: @JakeHenningsgaard, no git notes, see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes

Answer (score 2):

possibly the easiest way is to copy and remove the note:

For example, to move the HEAD notes to the previous commit,

```
# /!\ Be warned, this may be a destructive act

# git notes copy <source> <dest>
git notes copy HEAD HEAD^

# git notes remove <target>
git notes remove HEAD
```

---

P.S. notes are not automatically migrated when amending a commit.

Answer (score 0):

Note that with Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), "[`git notes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes) is more robust:

[`git note copy $original`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes#Documentation/git-notes.txt-copy) ought to copy the notes attached to the original object to `HEAD`, but a mistaken tightening to command line parameter validation made earlier disabled that feature by mistake.

See [commit d58deb9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d58deb9c4e151d4d8380cd14223391ce0d58f588), [commit 8af69cf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8af69cf3e214ee9df3f78bd508465b75881b17a8) (16 Oct 2019) by [Doan Tran Cong Danh (`congdanhqx-zz`)](https://github.com/congdanhqx-zz).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d4a98e7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d4a98e701f86bdff469d0f1ed912ba1651c23c3f), 10 Nov 2019)</sup>

> ### [`notes`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d58deb9c4e151d4d8380cd14223391ce0d58f588): fix minimum number of parameters to "`copy`" subcommand
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Doan Tran Cong Danh</sup>
>
> The [`builtin/notes.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d58deb9c4e151d4d8380cd14223391ce0d58f588/builtin/notes.c)::`copy()` function is prepared to handle either one or two arguments given from the command line; when one argument is given, `to-obj` defaults to `HEAD`.
>
> [bbb1b8a3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bbb1b8a35a06203020f7ab6d1ad58bcb4afe8e93) ("notes: check number of parameters to "[`git notes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes) copy"", 2010-06-28, Git v1.7.1.1) tried to make sure "[`git notes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes) copy" (with *no* other argument) does not dereference `NULL` by checking the number of parameters, but it incorrectly insisted that we need two arguments, instead of either one or two.
>
> This disabled the defaulting `to-obj` to `HEAD`.
>
> Correct it.

So now, `git notes copy -f HEAD~2` should work as `git notes copy -f HEAD~2 HEAD` and correctly override `HEAD` notes with the ones from two commits before `HEAD`.