# How to mark "release" commits in Git?

Tags: git, branch, release, git-branch, devops

I am editing the `master` branch in a git repo.

Time-to-time I test a commit and find that it works well. Then I may want to mark the last of such commits as *release*.

It can be done with branching, but this way I need to switch branches, to merge, to switch back, etc.

Is there an easier way to mark some of `master` releases as the *release*?

Comment: Use tags (lightweight or annotated, though generally for releases an annotated tag is better since you can store extra release data and/or GPG-sign it).

Comment: You can create tags without any switching and merging. If you're talking about GitHub, you can create releases from a specific commit using the UI.

Comment: @janos I do not want to invent a new tag name for every release. I want them to be denoted by some stable identifier like branch name. I am not talking about GitHub specifically

Answer (score 0):

You could consider notes, as in [`git notes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes).

You can mark any commit you want with a "release" note, and [move that marker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41452404/6309) (by copying and removing the old notes)

Answer (score 0):

Another option - besides using mentioned `git notes` is to use `git tag -a` (it creates an annotated tag), but aliased to automate the whole process.

The following alias may be added to `~/.gitconfig`:

```
release = !git tag -a release-$(git tag -l "release-*"|wc -l|sed 's/ //g')-$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)-$(git rev-parse HEAD)
```

It will create an annotated tag in the following form:

```
release-<release number>-<branch name>-<commit hash>
```

Note that you will be prompted to enter a tag message which cannot be empty. Of course you can customize the tag format to suit you needs. On every invocation new tag will be created. If you prefer a commit instead of a tag - it can used as well.

Also, when it comes to release process good idea is to follow [git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) rules - in original version or altered to suit your needs. When working with multiple branches and releasing from master you can configure a hook that will make a release (tag, note, whatever) automatically whenever a branch is merged to master.